# Finding $r''(t)=a+tb$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

How do you find

$r''(t)=a+tb$ for all real t

$r'(0)=c$

$r(0)=d$

I am not sure exatly what this is asking.

Comment: For suitably smooth functions, $x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t x'(\tau) d\tau$.

Comment: First let $x=r'$ and get a formula for $r'$, then repeat with $x=r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First integrate and put $t=o,r'=c$, integrate again and use $t=0,r=d$

Comment: ok I shall do that

Answer (score 0):

First take $\int r''(t) dt = r'(t)= \int (a+tb) dt  = at+ \frac b2t^2 + constant$

find $r'(0) = a(0)+ \frac b2(0)^2 + constant_1 = c$ to find that $constant_1 = c$

Then $\int r'(t) dt = r(t)= \int (at+ \frac b2t^2 + c) dt  = \frac a2t^2+ \frac b6t^3 + ct + constant_2$

Then $r(0) = \frac a2(0)^2+ \frac b6(0)^3 + c(0) + constant_2 = d$ gives $constant_2 = d$

so, $r(t) =\frac a2t^2+ \frac b6t^3 + ct + d$